401 after I add [authorize] to my endpoint, logs included
Nothing is working I tried everything, chatgpt, docs I think something is wrong but I don't know what!
My frontend is swagger, also when I check my JWT token on jwt.io, it seems to work.
Here are the logs in the middleware, you can clearly see that the token gets to the backend:
Twyt.Twyt.Api.Middleware.RequestLoggingMiddleware: Information: Handling request: GET /api/Post/user/82d3f35b-aa00-453b-80f5-2c06f2063e60

Twyt.Twyt.Api.Middleware.RequestLoggingMiddleware: Information: Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI4MmQzZjM1Yi1hYTAwLTQ1M2ItODBmNS0yYzA2ZjIwNjNlNjAiLCJqdGkiOiJjYzYwZWNlMi0wZDE0LTQ3NWEtOTcxOC00NWYwMzhiM2VhZmIiLCJleHAiOjE3MjY0MTc1NDksImlzcyI6IlR3eXQiLCJhdWQiOiJUd3l0In0.UN8rtNhp6HI7Ut6ovUOTYBFmYHneHHbN8XblZRZ3PlU
Program: Warning: Token is null or empty
Loaded Assembly '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.8/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'
Loading module /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.8/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll in application domain 1:clrhost
Pdb file for assembly /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.8/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll was not found or failed to read
Loaded Assembly '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.8/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'
Loading module /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.8/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll in application domain 1:clrhost
Pdb file for assembly /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.8/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll was not found or failed to read
Loaded Assembly '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.8/System.Collections.Immutable.dll'
Loading module /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.8/System.Collections.Immutable.dll in application domain 1:clrhost
Pdb file for assembly /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.8/System.Collections.Immutable.dll was not found or failed to read
Program: Error: Authentication failed: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenMalformedException: IDX14100: JWT is not well formed, there are no dots (.).
The token needs to be in JWS or JWE Compact Serialization Format. (JWS): 'EncodedHeader.EndcodedPayload.EncodedSignature'. (JWE): 'EncodedProtectedHeader.EncodedEncryptedKey.EncodedInitializationVector.EncodedCiphertext.EncodedAuthenticationTag'.
 ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Byte[] Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Base64UrlEncoder.UnsafeDecode(System.ReadOnlyMemory`1<Char>)'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebToken.ReadToken(String encodedJson)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebToken..ctor(String jwtEncodedString)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebTokenHandler.ReadToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Program: Warning: OnChallenge error: invalid_token
Twyt.Twyt.Api.Middleware.RequestLoggingMiddleware: Information: Finished handling request. Status code: 401
Twyt.Twyt.Api.Middleware.RequestLoggingMiddleware: Warning: Unauthorized access attempt: GET /api/Post/user/82d3f35b-aa00-453b-80f5-2c06f2063e60

Token Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{           
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"] ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("JWT Key is not configured"));

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"] ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("JWT Issuer is not configured"),
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"] ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("JWT Audience is not configured"),
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
    };
    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true; 
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogError("Authentication failed: {Exception}", context.Exception.ToString());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnChallenge = context =>
        {
            var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogWarning("OnChallenge error: {0}", context.Error);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            var token = context.Token;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                logger.LogWarning("Token is null or empty");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            // Log the raw token for debugging
            logger.LogInformation("Token received: {Token}", token);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

And this is the generateToken function as you can see it uses the variables from appsettings.json:
public async Task<string> GenerateJwtToken(User user)
{
    var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]));
    var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserId.ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(2),
                signingCredentials: credentials
            );

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}


add also program.cs code to

Says the JWT is missing dots, are you able to parse in jwt.io?

The issue might relate the Security token change or the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer version. You can check it and try to use the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 8.0.8 version.
According to your code and description, I create a sample with the following steps, the JWT Authorization works well.

Create a new .NET 8 API application via the Asp.net core Web API template (using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.11.1).

Install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 8.0.8 version.

Add Jwt key, Issuer and Audience in appsettings.json file:
   {
     "Logging": {
       "LogLevel": {
         "Default": "Information",
         "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
       }
     },
     "AllowedHosts": "*",
     "Jwt": {
       "Audience": "http://localhost:4200",
       "Issuer": "http://localhost:5000",
       "Key": "JWTAuthenticationHIGHsecuredPasswordVVVp1OH7Xzyr"
     }
   }


Configure JWT service in Program.cs file:
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
 using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
 using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
 using System.Text;

 var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
 ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;

 // Add services to the container.

 builder.Services.AddControllers();
 // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
 builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
 //builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


 builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options => {
     options.SwaggerDoc("V1", new OpenApiInfo
     {
         Version = "V1",
         Title = "WebAPI",
         Description = "Product WebAPI"
     });
     options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
     {
         Scheme = "Bearer",
         BearerFormat = "JWT",
         In = ParameterLocation.Header,
         Name = "Authorization",
         Description = "Bearer Authentication with JWT Token",
         Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http
     });
     options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
         {
             new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                 Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                     Id = "Bearer",
                         Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                 }
             },
             new List < string > ()
         }
     });
 });

 // Adding Authentication
 builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
 {
     options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 })

 // Adding Jwt Bearer
 .AddJwtBearer(options =>
 {
     options.SaveToken = true;
     options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
     options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
     {
         ValidateIssuer = true,
         ValidateAudience = true,
         ValidateLifetime = true,
         ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
         ValidAudience = configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
         ValidIssuer = configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
         IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
     };
     options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
     options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
     {
         OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
         {
             var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
             logger.LogError("Authentication failed: {Exception}", context.Exception.ToString());
             return Task.CompletedTask;
         },
         OnChallenge = context =>
         {
             var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
             logger.LogWarning("OnChallenge error: {0}", context.Error);
             return Task.CompletedTask;
         },
         OnMessageReceived = context =>
         {
             var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
             var token = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
             {
                 logger.LogWarning("Token is null or empty");
                 return Task.CompletedTask;
             }

             // Log the raw token for debugging
             logger.LogInformation("Token received: {Token}", token);

             return Task.CompletedTask;
         }
     };
 });

 var app = builder.Build();

 if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
 {
     app.UseSwagger();
     app.UseSwaggerUI(options => {
         options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/V1/swagger.json", "Product WebAPI");
     });
 }

 app.UseHttpsRedirection();

 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();

 app.MapControllers();

 app.Run();


Add Account controller as below:
 using Core8APIJWT.Models; 
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
 using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
 using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
 using System.Security.Claims;
 using System.Text;

 // For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

 namespace Core8APIJWT.Controllers
 {
     [Route("api/[controller]")]
     [ApiController]
     public class AccountController : ControllerBase
     {
         private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

         public AccountController(IConfiguration configuration) { 
             _configuration=configuration;
         }

         [HttpPost]
         [Route("login")]
         public async Task<string> Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
         { 
             if (model.Username == "Admin" && model.Password == "password")
             { 
                 var authClaims = new List<Claim>
                 {
                     new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"),
                     new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                 }; 
                 var token = GetToken(authClaims);
                 return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token); 
             }
             return "Unauthorized";  
         }
         private JwtSecurityToken GetToken(List<Claim> authClaims)
         {
             var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"])); 
             var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

             var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                 issuer: _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                 audience: _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                 expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
                 claims: authClaims,
                 signingCredentials: credentials
                 );

             return token;
         }
     }
 }


Add the Authorize attribute on the security endpoint.
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

 namespace Core8APIJWT.Controllers
 {
     [Authorize]
     [ApiController]
     [Route("[controller]")]
     public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
     {
        ...


After running the application and add the JWT token to the request header, the request is success, result as below: As we can see, we can get the token in the OnMessageReceived event.



In my sample, it just installs the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer version.

Besides, I also find this similar issue, you can refer it.

I do recall I got this issue when I updated my API for .net 7 to .net 8
the fix for me was to install this package. It worked like a charm

dotnet add package Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens

U can follow up on this issue here if you did not get it to work by installing the package https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52286
